# Trying to install a package using pip but getting this error "the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: python

In the command window I ran this:

```
python -mpip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install django
```

But getting the error. It looks like some problem with my environment settings, but I've checked them and they look fine. Anyone seen this issue before?

```
Installing collected packages: django
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\lyu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\;C:'
```

Comment: What environment variable has that value?

Comment: The 2nd path element  (the C: at the end) has a colon but no backslash.